# XML Files not copied to iOS Export of Unity 3D Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I made a game which has level files stored in .xml format. I have put these files in the Assets > Resources Folder. These files are loaded and parsed when the game starts. In the editor that all works fine.

However, one I export the game for iOS I can't find the xml files in the Xcode project. Am I missing a step here?

Thanks for any help and kind regards

Comment: You could expose a TextAsset field on one of your behaviours, and assign the xml file to that field.  Then you can access the data using `myTextAsset.text`.  This will ensure the file is not stripped from the build (not sure why the file is actually missing).  [Text Asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html)

Comment: `I can't find the xml files in the Xcode project.` can you still load them though? See e.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/resources-folder-contents-not-found-after-ios-build.137029/ -> `Anything in Resources will be compiled to a .NET Resources assembly and cease to exist as files at all.
You must use Resources.Load with the path relative to the Resources folder. Nothing else will work.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find the xml files in the Xcode project.

You should still be able to load them though using [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

See e.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/resources-folder-contents-not-found-after-ios-build.137029/#post-932250

> Anything in Resources will be compiled to a .NET Resources assembly and cease to exist as files at all.
> You must use Resources.Load with the path relative to the Resources folder. Nothing else will work.

---

In general though [Don't use Resources](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

There are may alternatives like e.g.

- the mentioned [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html)
- rather using [`StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)
- go for [`Addressables`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.21/manual/index.html) (can be local or side loaded)

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks a lot for your reply! I won't be able to try the stuff you recommended until next week but I am confident it'll work. Thanks for the clarifications. Very helpful!

Comment: But one more thing. I am using Resources.Load to load the XML files as text asset. In editor everything works perfectly fine while only when deployed it doesn't work. Does that smell like a cause for problems you are familiar with?

Comment: @BobTheBuilder tbh no, I would expect it to work the same as in the editor according to the sample `//Load text from a JSON file (Assets/Resources/Text/jsonFile01.json) var jsonTextFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/jsonFile01");`